# Rethrowing specific exceptions to UI layer and Too Much Information principle

Tags: exception

If you are rethrowing an exception to the UI layer (so the user will see it) is it always wise to rethrow a specific exception (Eg argumentnullexception)?

The problem I've seen with this is that it is too much technical information to he user. All I need to know is the problem and the cause, hiding any details and not even mention the word exception.

I saw the rethrowing of a specific exception in some code I was reviewing and was wondering if this is really recommended?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you doing with the exception once it reaches the UI layer?

If you're just letting the system exception handler catch it and shut down your program, then *the more specific the better*, because the user won't be seeing it anyway.

If you're catching it in the UI layer and telling the user what went wrong, then *the more specific the better*, and the UI layer can worry about "prettying it up" so that the user isn't bamboozled by too much technical information.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any exceptions should *ever* be thrown to the UI tier.  It ought to be caught, logged, and translated into something meaningful for a user.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging the specific exception?  If the answer is yes, I would say rethrow a general exception.  I assume that you have a `try/catch` block in your UI tier that does something that makes sense, like display a message box with the error message in the exception.

Comment: Logging, yes. Try/catch, yep.